# Should I download scripts from a CDN or bundle everything into one script?

Tags: bundling

I am using jQuery, angular, bootstrap, along with some custom js files.  Currently, I have everything bundled into one script.  Since, jQuery, angular, and bootstrap are available via CDN, is it better to just grab them from the CDN or should I keep those bundled with my scripts?

Comment: Better by what metric?

Comment: @Neil - In general, but I would say speed and size?

Comment: Combining the files reduces the number of requests, which can speed download. Pulling the files from a CDN that is widely used improves the chance that the files will already be present in the user's cache from visiting other sites.  If they haven't, though, they'll get slowed down from additional DNS and HTTP requests.  `

Comment: Most people tend to prefer bundling, as you don't depend on another server being up to work and you only have to download a single script once.

Comment: I ran across this answer and felt it explains bundling well http://stackoverflow.com/a/28233712/32240

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to bundle all of your own scripts together, and load common third party scripts from a CDN. It gives you the best of both worlds - your scripts download quickly, and third party scripts are likely loaded directly from the end user's cache.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Have a copy of these scripts in your repository otherwise you are totally dependent of CDN content management. Same goes for any js lib you might been using.  Js ecosystem is quite fragil and volatile.